# Include 3rd party library in Eclipse CDT with Visual Studio Toolchain

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I'm pretty new to using 3rd party libraries and such, and I need some help getting Eclipse CDT configured to link to the dynamic SDL2.dll library and be able to read the code from the header files in this 3rd party library. A lot of examples seem to be of linux system set-ups using GCC and such, but I'm trying to get it to work with the Visual Studio toolchain already installed on my PC.

Path to header files: C:\SDL2-2.0.5\include

Path to .dll and .lib files: C:\SDL2-2.0.5\lib\x64

Code:

```
#include "C:\SDL2-2.0.5\include\SDL.h"

int main() {
    SDL_SetMainReady();
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO)!=0){
        SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried adding the include path to the header files under Project>Properties>C/C++ General>Paths and Symbols>Includes>GNU C++(and GNU C), and I've tried adding the library path to "SDL2.dll" under Project>Properties>C/C++ General>Paths and Symbols>Libraries. The IDE still said it was unable to resolve the function calls; despite there being no issue with the #include "C:\SDL2-2.0.5\include\SDL.h" line.

I also tried adding the library path under Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Settings>Linker(link)>Libraries. Under "Additional libpath" i put: "C:\SDL2-2.0.5\lib\x64" and under "Libraries" I put: "C:\SDL2-2.0.5\lib\x64\SDL2.dll"; still with no success.

I even tried adding the include path to the .h files in the INCLUDE environment variable and the path to the .dll file in the PATH envirnment variable under Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, dynamic libraries have two parts: the `.dll` that contains the executable code and is needed at runtime and a `.lib` which is the import library that tells the linker to find the externals in the `.dll`. So, under "Libraries" you need to specify the import library (`.lib`). And put the `.dll` somewhere the executable can find it at runtime, e.g. in the same folder.

Comment: Well i was finally able to get the IDE to resolve the function calls, and I set "Libraries" to the "SDL2.lib" file, but when I build the program I get this error: "LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined". When I run the program this error: "Launching New Project.exe has encountered a problem. The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist." Which is due to not being able to find the .exe file for the project. Though I thought it should build it? Also, I placed the .dll file into a libs folder in the project's folder.

Comment: The executable will not be created when there's a fatal linker error. For some reason the linker can't identify the program entry point, which should be defined by `int main()`.
So we come on to some questions: are you using Microsoft `CL` or `GCC`; are you running under `MinGW`; have you tried building a simple `Hello World` program just to test your setup? But the biggest question of all has to be why are you using Eclipse on Windows? Visual Studio Community is free and just works.